# C# playing a video file

Tags: c#, video, shared-libraries, media-player

```
this.Background = new System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush(new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(MY URL HERE)));
```

The above code helps me to display an image control along with its image.
I want to play a video file.

Does the `System.Windows.Media` library has any method to play the video file ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF you can try this:

```
// 
// Create a VideoDrawing. 
//      
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

player.Open(new Uri(@"sampleMedia\xbox.wmv", UriKind.Relative));

VideoDrawing aVideoDrawing = new VideoDrawing();

aVideoDrawing.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);

aVideoDrawing.Player = player;

DrawingBrush brush = new DrawingBrush(aVideoDrawing);
this.Background = brush;

// Play the video once.
player.Play();
```

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969812.aspx

Comment: Create a DrawingBrush and set the background to the drawing brush. I edited the example. I tried it and it works fine. If you get a black screen the Uri may be wrong. Let me here if it works out

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [Videobrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189009%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Let me know if that works for you.